# Converting byte[] to string storing decimal value in string in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, string-conversion

How do I convert a `byte[]` to a `string`? Every time I attempt it, I get

> System.Byte[]

instead of the value.

Also, how do I get the value in decimal instead of hexadecimal?

using the below code I'm getting in hexadecimal only

```
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(data);
```

here is my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program obj = new Program();
    byte[] byteData;
    int n;

    byteData = GetBytesFromHexString("001C0014500C0A5B06A4FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF");
    n = byteData.Length;

    string s = BitConverter.ToString(byteData);
    Console.WriteLine("<Command Value='" + s + "'/>");
    Console.WriteLine("</AudioVideo>");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static byte[] GetBytesFromHexString(string hexString)
{
    if (hexString == null)
        return null;

    if (hexString.Length % 2 == 1)
        hexString = '0' + hexString; // Up to you whether to pad the first or last byte

    byte[] data = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        data[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    Console.WriteLine(data);
    return data;
}
```

output should be:

> 0 28 0 20 80 12 10 91 6 164 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
>   255 255 255 255

output should be stored in a string and displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the line

```
string s = BitConverter.ToString(byteData);
```

with

```
string s = string.Join(" ", byteData.Select(b => b.ToString()));
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: Working for me as well